# sp_executesql gives unclosed quotation mark error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-executesql

I've written simple stored procedure and executing using sp_executesql to tackle with quotation error and sql injection as well but when i pass a single quote in parameter still it shows me `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.`

```
alter procedure dbo.quote_test
(
    @quoteid int
)
as
begin
declare @sqlstring as nvarchar(max)
declare @paramdef as nvarchar(100)
set @sqlstring = 'select * from quote where quote_id = @quoteid';
set @paramdef = N'@quoteid int';
exec sp_executesql @sqlstring,@paramdef, @quoteid
end

exec dbo.quote_test 10'
```

Comment: This page comes up high on Google searches... could you please select which of the below answered the problem... or tell us your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the stored procedure takes an integer for an argument.  So, this will work:

```
exec dbo.quote_test 10
```

This should not work:

```
exec dbo.quote_test 'abc'
```

Comment: But what if I'm taking string as a parameter sp_execute will escape it?

Comment: Like this exec dbo.quote_test '10'' gives quotation error.

Comment: It looks like you have defined your function to accept an INT as the argument.  Like @Gordon says, you would need to pass it in as an INT and not within quotes -> '10'

Comment: @MatthewatCriticalCognition . . . Well, if you pass in `'10'`, then SQL Server will probably convert that to an int.  If you pass in `'10a'`, you should get an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - you are correct.  mr_eclair - I think your issue might be that you have a single quote to begin your parameter but a double quote or double tick to end it.

Comment: @mr_eclair . . . The quotes have to balance in a SQL expression.  In `exec dbo.quote_test '10''`, you have an unclosed string.  If you had `exec dbo.quote_test '10''a'`, then the argument to the function would be `10'a`, with a single quote in the string -- and an error because the function wants an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to your EXEC statement that has the quote.

exec dbo.quote_test 10'